# Can you use a Legendary in a Gym Battle?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know you cannot place a Legendary Pokemon in a Gym to defend is, and I do know that you can use a Legendary to fight a Raid Boss.
But I hear some people saying that you also cannot use a Legendary to attack a Gym. Does anyone know if that is true?

Comment: Is this not something incredibly easy to test?

Comment: @Frank U couldn't test it. I only have 3 Gyms in my neighbourhood (rural) and all of them are from my team at the moment. Blue is on vacation I guess. But somebody said you couldn't and somebody else said you could use them. So it was confusing.

Comment: Why is my question getting minned, for me it is avalid question. I did reseach and Legendary are not like normal pokemon.:- S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to do this. I just used an Articuno to attack a gym, myself.

[image: battle party]

[image: a new challenger approaches]

[image: gg dragonite]

You can also use multiples of the same legendary in a gym battle. The most extreme case is shown in this video:

The trainer uses a team of 6 Articuno to attack a gym.

Comment: Did you win though?

Comment: @n_palum yeah, Articuno did work (the defending Pokémon had pretty low CP, though, to be fair)

Comment: I now also have an Articuno. Now i also tried it out on an Gym, and the attacking idd worked. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use Legendary Pokémon in raid and gym battles

[Niantic Updates](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/legendarypokemon)

> While Legendary Pokémon will help them take on the toughest Raid Bosses and Gym Battles, they’re not willing to leave their Trainer’s side, so they can’t be left to defend Gyms.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use legendary Pokémon to attack Gyms.